# Scrappeando con beatifulsoup al intentar obtener el texto en sección uno obtengo el error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, scraping

Utilizando las librerías BeautifulSoup y Requests intenté scrappear la navigation list de https://rpp.pe/

```
import requests
url= 'https://rpp.pe/'
rpp = requests.get(url)
rpp.status_code
rpp.request.method
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = BeautifulSoup(rpp.text , 'lxml')
type(s)
secciones = s.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'main-menu'}).find_all('a')
secciones
seccion = secciones[0]
seccion.a.get_text()
```

aquí me da el mensaje 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Cuando creas `secciones` ya estas buscando todas las etiquetas `<a>`

```
secciones = s.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'main-menu'}).find_all('a')
```

Por lo que únicamente tienes que utilizar `get_text()` directamente en `secciones[0]` que vendría siendo `seccion`

Ejemplo completo (Reorganizado para verlo mejor):

**Nota:** Creo que usas JupyterNotebook o algo similar pero siempre es mejor poner el código en modo "plano", por eso agregué todos los `print()` para mostrar la información completa de las variables.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rpp.pe/'
rpp = requests.get(url)
print(rpp.status_code)
print(rpp.request.method)

s = BeautifulSoup(rpp.text , 'lxml')
print(type(s))

secciones = s.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'main-menu'}).find_all('a')
print(secciones)
seccion = secciones[0]
print(seccion.get_text())
```

Esto devuelve:

```
200
GET
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
[<a href="https://rpp.pe/archivo">Últimas noticias</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/politica">Política</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/actualidad">Actualidad</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/peru">Perú</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/deportes">Deportes</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/mundo">Mundo</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/economia">Economía</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/entretenimiento">Entretenimiento</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/tecno">Tecnología</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/vital">Vital</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/audio/">Radio</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/columnistas">Columnistas</a>, <a href="https://rpp.pe/blog">Blogs</a>]
Últimas noticias
```

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionar con `secciones = s.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'main-menu'}).find_all('div')`

Comment: No olvides explicar cómo funciona tu código. Puede que vos comprendas cómo funciona, pero otros usuarios que podrían beneficiarse de tu pregunta/respuesta puede que no. Lee [answer] y [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.